# How to make the following template helper reactive (Meteor)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have `Chapters` collection, and I show a list of chapters in one of the templates:

```
<template name="chapterItem">
  <div class="chapter clearfix {{isCurrentChapter}}">
    <div class="chapter-arrows">
      <a class="move-up" href="javascript:;"><i class="ion-arrow-up-a"></i></a>
      <a class="move-down" href="javascript:;"><i class="ion-arrow-down-a"></i></a>
    </div>
    <h4><a class="open-chapter" href="javascript:;">{{title}}</a></h4>
    <a class="delete-current-chapter" href="javascript:;"><i class="ion-close-circled"></i></a>
  </div>
</template>
```

As you can see, I created a `isCurrentChapter` to use like this:

```
// book_page.js
Template.bookPage.events
  "click .open-chapter": function() {
    localStorage.setItem "currentChapter", this._id
  }

// chapter_item.js
Template.chapterItem.helpers({
  isCurrentChapter: function() {
    var currentChapterId = localStorage.getItem("currentChapter");
    var selectedChapterId = this._id;
    if selectedChapterId === currentChapterId) {
      return "active";
    }
  }
});
```

The problem now is that the `active` is returned only changes when the page loads.

How can I do it so that `isCurrentChapter` becomes reactive? Fires up on the `click .open-chapter` event?

Comment: Do it with sessions instead of localStorage, they are reactive, and I assume it's just a typo but ur last if isn't closed

Comment: @Sindis I forgot why I changed sessions for `localStorage`. I think I needed the value to persist on page reload.

Comment: Then you should force reactivity with Tracker http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun

Comment: @Sindis I tried that (I enclosed the inside section of `isCurrentChapter` with Tracker.autorun), but got `[Object] object` instead of the `active`.

Comment: https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session Persistent Session ftw then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make helper reactive, it must depend on reactive source. We can use Session.

```
// book_page.js
Template.bookPage.events({
  "click .open-chapter": function() {
    Session.set('currentChapter', this._id);
    localStorage.setItem("currentChapter", this._id);
  }
});

// chapter_item.js
Template.chapterItem.helpers({
  isCurrentChapter: function() {
    var currentChapterId = Session.get("currentChapter");
    var selectedChapterId = this._id;
    if (selectedChapterId === currentChapterId) {
      return "active";
    }
  }
});
```

When session "currentChapter" changes, the helper isCurrentChapter re-runs.

**EDIT:** If you want to set active class on page load or refresh you can do something like this:

```
var currentChapterId = Session.get("currentChapter") || localStorage.getItem("currentChapter");
```

Try to get currentChapter from session, if it's undefined, then get it from localStorage. Or use Session.setDefault on top of your code:

```
Session.setDefault('currentChapter', localStorage.getItem('currentChapter'));
```

Comment: But after reload Session will be lost, and no chapter will be highlighted, I think that was authors main concern for not using sessions